# Nginx Wordpress with magento 1.9

Tags: nginx, magento

I am currently trying to move our sites from apache and subdomains to nginx and the removal of subdomains.

Currently my folder structure has wordpress as the main directory and the shops living in a folder called shops.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/test.local;


    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name test.local;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /proshop {
        alias /var/www/test.local/shops;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @nested {
        rewrite /proshop/(.*)$ /shops/index.php?/$1 last;
    }


    location /shop {

        alias /var/www/test.local/shops;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @shop;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }

    location @shop {
        rewrite /shop/(.*)$ /shops/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is:

domain.com/proshop/ shows me my homepage allbeit with broken styling and js.....

however if i try

domain.com/proshop/admin

to get to the admin area i am hitting a 404?